# Rails URL question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a Users model, and then an individual user, say, person1, is there a way to have the url: `www.myapp.com/person1` show what `www.myapp.com/users/person1` would? What would that be called?

Thank you!

Comment: Check `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html` Also, your implementation will be a bit ambiguous, for example, what if user has a username `users`? or username that is equal to one of model names in your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define a route in your `routes.rb` file:

```
match "/:user" => "users#show"
```

and you'll get the username given in `params[:user]`. But you need to know that this kind of route could override other routes defined, because it will match any string, so you should at least define some constraints on the username.

For example if your usernames matches a regexp you could define it as a constraint

```
match "/:user" => "users#show", :constraints => { :user => /some-regexp/ }
```

and don't forget to set this route as the last one in your routes file, otherwise it will clash for sure with other routes.

Read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for full reference

Comment: awesome. Thank you, Fabio! I'll acccept it once I'm able to.

Comment: @ConnorMontgomery: I added some more details in the answer. P.S. You can always accept an answer, even with 1 rep ;-)

Comment: Yeah I know - it just says I needed to wait 7 minutes... 1 minute now. Once that time delta is done, I'll accept it ;)

And thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

add "two" routes for the same thing to your app.

```
 # Shorter url to show store items by tags
map.connect '/s/tags',
  :controller => 'music',
  :action     => 'show_by_tags'
map.connect '/music/s/tags',
  :controller => 'music',
  :action     => 'show_by_tags'
```